# What is a for-loop with the for-loop at the end of it called in python?

Tags: python

I've seen some snippets of python code in which a loop was written as follows:

```
someList = g.db.execute('SELECT title, body FROM posts')
posts = [dict(title=x[0],body=[1]) for x in someList.fetchAll()]
```

What is this kind of loop refered to as?

I realize it could be just refered to as a for loop, but the syntax it quite different from a c-based language (shorter and more productive), so I just wondered if have some other name written like this.

Comment: This is a list comprehension.

Comment: Please note it is defintely _not_ a loop, but rather a single expression, called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Generally, I see this type loops under comprehension, such as list comprehension or set comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This is list comprehension, these are equivalent:

```
[dict(title=x[0],body=[1]) for x in someList]

for x in someList:
    dict(title = x[0], body = [1])
```